# How I can integrate Razorpay in website using JavaScript or Java?

Tags: javascript, java

I am totally a beginner in payment gateway no idea how to approach it. But I went through Razorpay side and all the other stackoverflow questions and from 2 days I am struggling to integrate the Razorpay gateway in my project. Now I am approaching the payment gateway by using JavaScript.
My project is a online shopping website which is based on java but I used JavaScript for giving the functionality in the website.

1. I don't have any idea about Reactjs and I am trying to integrate the gateway using basic Js.
   directly into the jsp .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/razorpay.js"></script>
</head>
<input type="button" id="razorGateway" name="submit" class="submit action-button"
                                    value="Pay" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            var options = {
            "key": "rzp_test_1234567UHGSssj", // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
            "amount": "50000", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise or INR 500.
            "currency": "INR",
            "name": "Acme Corp",
            "description": "Ecommerce",
            "image": "image",
            "order_id": "order_9A33XWu170gUtm",//This is a sample Order ID. Create an Order using Orders API. (https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/orders/integration/#step-1-create-an-order). Refer the Checkout form table given below
            "handler": function (response){
                alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
            },
            "prefill": {
                "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
                "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
                "contact": "9999999999"
            },
            "notes": {
                "address": "note value"
            },
            "theme": {
                "color": "#EA5B29"
            }
        };
        var rzp1 = new window.Razorpay(options);
        document.getElementById('razorGateway').onclick = function(e){
            rzp1.open();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
</script>
```

After debugging I am getting an error message. rzp1.open().
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU3an.png)

---

When I am not able to integrate with above method I went with another way.

```
<script>
    // Single instance on page.
      var razorpay = new Razorpay({
      key: 'rzp_test_1234567UHGSssj',
        // logo, displayed in the payment processing popup
      image: 'https://i.imgur.com/n5tjHFD.png',
      });

    //Fetching the payment.
      razorpay.once('ready', function(response) {
      console.log(response.methods);
      })

     //Submitting the data.
     var data = {
              amount: 1000, // in currency subunits. Here 1000 = 1000 paise, which equals to ₹10
              currency: "INR",// Default is INR. We support more than 90 currencies.
              email: 'test.appmomos@gmail.com',
              contact: '9123456780',
              notes: {
                address: 'Ground Floor, SJR Cyber, Laskar Hosur Road, Bengaluru',
              },
             // order_id: '123',
              method: 'netbanking',
              // method specific fields
              bank: 'HDFC'
     };

    $("#razorGateway").click (function(){
        alert("payment clicked");
  // has to be placed within user initiated context, such as click, in order for popup to open.
     razorpay.createPayment(data);

          razorpay.on('payment.success', function(resp) {
              alert("payment checking.");
            alert(resp.razorpay_payment_id),
            alert(resp.razorpay_order_id),
            alert(resp.razorpay_signature)}); // will pass payment ID, order ID, and Razorpay signature to success handler.

          razorpay.on('payment.error', function(resp){alert(resp.error.description)}); // will pass error object to error handler

})
</script>
```

Here I am able to hit the razorpay and pop-up is also visible but as it is hard coded I am not able to get the various options of payment method as it is shown in the demo. Directly it is giving me success and fail message(last page of gateway).
https://razorpay.com/demo

This option I am not getting it.[Different payment methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnH0b.png)

I will be at cloud no.9 if I get the answer or I am able to integrate it in either way or any other way. If options of integrating in Java is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

***Hi***, i think you need to generate an actual `order_id` from server side as it is mentioned in their docs [here](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/standard/). Instead of the sample `order id`.

Answer (score 0):

The Below Code Works.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PaymentGateway</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/razorpay.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Single instance on page.
  var razorpay = new Razorpay({
    key: 'rzp_test_tCLhPLootU4w3M',
    // logo, displayed in the payment processing popup
    image: 'https://i.imgur.com/n5tjHFD.png',
  });

  // Fetching the payment.
  razorpay.once('ready', function(response) {
    console.log(response.methods);
  });

  // Submitting the data.
  var data = {
    amount: 1000, // in currency subunits. Here 1000 = 1000 paise, which equals to ₹10
    currency: "INR", // Default is INR. We support more than 90 currencies.
    email: 'test.appmomos@gmail.com',
    contact: '9123456780',
    notes: {
      address: 'Ground Floor, SJR Cyber, Laskar Hosur Road, Bengaluru',
    },
    // order_id: '123',
    method: 'netbanking',
    // method specific fields
    bank: 'HDFC'
  };

  $("#razorGateway").click(function() {
    alert("Payment clicked");
    // has to be placed within a user-initiated context, such as click, in order for popup to open.
    razorpay.createPayment(data);

    razorpay.on('payment.success', function(resp) {
      alert("Payment success.");
      alert(resp.razorpay_payment_id);
      alert(resp.razorpay_order_id);
      alert(resp.razorpay_signature);
    }); // will pass payment ID, order ID, and Razorpay signature to success handler.

    razorpay.on('payment.error', function(resp) {
      alert(resp.error.description);
    }); // will pass error object to error handler
  });
});
</script>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="razorGateway" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Pay" />
</body>
</html>
```